# Installing turtlebot on kinetic

Tags: ros

i am installing a turtlebot on my kinetic running on ubuntu 16.04, i have followed this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9U6GDonGFHw&feature=youtu.be on 17:10 and replace the word 'indigo' to 'kinetic' in the sudo apt-get install, however i receive error such as Unable to locate package ros-kinetic-turtlebot-simulator/Unable to locate package ros-kinetic-rocon-remocon/Unable to locate package ros-kinetic-rocon-qt-library.

Is there anyone who can help me out on this. Thanks

I have already tried different setups such as git clone some of the individual packages from http://wiki.ros.org/Robots/TurtleBot/kinetic but it is not working yet.

Answer (score 0):

Please set up the sources.list first as mentioned in the 1.2 sub section of the Wiki installation of ROS Kinetic http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Well i have faced the same problem, I did follow all the instructions in the video, however the installation was for `indigo`, changing just the word `kinetic` doesn't work so i found a solution, use `apt-cache search ros-kinetic` . This will show a long list of packages supported by `ros kinetic` and yes there is a list of all turtlebot related packages. To install use the usual `sudo apt-get install <pkg_name>`. You have to install all the packages one by one manually there is no single code line that would install all the packages relate to turtlebot, however you can install all at-once by just adding all the package name next to each other like this `sudo apt-get install <pkg_name1> <pkg_name2> <pkg_name3>........`, press "y" to install and then to check installation do this `roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_world.launch`

You can also install other packages like this when you are unable to find a source to install.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to install Turtlebot for Kinetic

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-turtlebot ros-kinetic-turtlebot-actions ros-kinetic-turtlebot-apps ros-kinetic-turtlebot-bringup ros-kinetic-turtlebot-calibration ros-kinetic-turtlebot-capabilities ros-kinetic-turtlebot-create ros-kinetic-turtlebot-dashboard ros-kinetic-turtlebot-description ros-kinetic-turtlebot-follower ros-kinetic-turtlebot-gazebo ros-kinetic-turtlebot-interactions ros-kinetic-turtlebot-interactive-markers ros-kinetic-turtlebot-loadout-kha1 ros-kinetic-turtlebot-msgs ros-kinetic-turtlebot-navigation ros-kinetic-turtlebot-rapps ros-kinetic-turtlebot-rviz-launchers ros-kinetic-turtlebot-simulator ros-kinetic-turtlebot-stage ros-kinetic-turtlebot-stdr ros-kinetic-turtlebot-teleop
```

Also in some cases, you will find some issues with dependencies. Do

```
source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash
```

Hope this will help!